# Exchange migration failure: Active Directory property 'homeMDB' is not writeable on recipient

Tags: exchange, exchange-migration

Performing an Exchange 2016 on-prem mailbox migration and receiving the following error;

**Active Directory property 'homeMDB' is not writeable on recipient..**

I've ensured that inheritable permissions are turned on for the AD object, and even went ahead and disabled\re-enabled them to try and force permission re-sync, still receiving the same error when trying to resume the mailbox migration.

Comment: found [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/troubleshoot/migration/ad-property-homemdb-not-writeable), [this also](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/8c97e79d-1cf1-432a-ad25-e23094474ef9/move-request-fails-with-quotactive-directory-property-homemdb-is-not-writeable-on?forum=Exch2016Adm)  - did you done the research before posting, as this is a must requirement for asking in here?

Comment: @djdomi Both of those articles reference resetting inheritable permissions, which I mentioned above that was the first thing I tried. So yes, I read those same articles, yes I did research, and yes I attempted that recommended fix. For step 2 in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/troubleshoot/migration/ad-property-homemdb-not-writeable) link, these conditions are already true, as this would impact my other migrations if it were not true.